# No wifi connections detected [Realtek RTL8822BE]

Tags: wireless, realtek

When I turn on the laptop the wifi is connected, few seconds latter it disconects and cant find any wifi networks

my wifi adapter is:
Realtek RTL8822BE

lshw -C network
return this:

```
*-generic                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Illegal Vendor ID
       vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: ff
       serial: 0c:96:e6:c9:e6:d3
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822be driverversion=5.4.0-58-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:145 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4300000-a430ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 15
       serial: e8:6a:64:9f:0a:5c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.203 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
```

when its working

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 00
       serial: 0c:96:e6:c9:e6:d3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822be driverversion=5.4.0-58-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:145 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4300000-a430ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 15
       serial: e8:6a:64:9f:0a:5c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.203 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
```

Comment: This looks a bug to me. You can report it by running `ubuntu-bug linux`

Answer (score 0):

To make sure networking stays on, make sure to turn off power management.

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

which is editing the network manager configuration file. Can also edit the file manually, for example:

```
xed admin:///etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Find the section

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

and change `3` into `2`.